# What is the possible loop invariant

Tags: algorithm, loop-invariant

Could someone provide a possible loop invariant for the following simple algorithm:

Input: `A[0,...,n-1]` and `B[0,...,m-1]`, each might contain repeated elements

Output: the first pair of (i,j) such that `A[i] == B[j]`.

Algorithm:

```
for i <- 0 to n-1
    for j <- 0 to m-1
        if A[i] = B[j] then
           return (i,j)
        endif
    endfor
endfor
return null
```

So far, I've got only one solution that might or might not work:

`S = {(i,j) | A[0,...,i-1] and B[0,...,j-1] has no common elements}`

Comment: Are the arrays sorted?

Comment: What is the "first pair of ..." - the one with the smallest `i`? The smallest `j`? The smallest `i+j`? There is more than one possible ordering of the pairs, so you'll have to specify what that means before you can get an answer... For example, if `A[0] == B[m-1]`, would that be "first" over `A[1] == B[1]`?

Comment: @twalberg The loop invariant of the algorithm shown above.  I think with the algorithm specified, the *first pair* should be clear :)

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the `qth` iteration of the second loop inside the `pth` iteration of the first loop, `A[i] != B[j]` for all `i = 0...p - 1, j = 0...q - 1`.

Comment: basically, your solution is identical to what i've included in my question.  Actually this is the only one i've worked out.  Theoretically, infinite numbers should be found...